# Count loops in foreach and act based on that

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Hi i have a function in PHP, which returns colors of my products in woocommerce.

My function:

```
global $product;

                if ( $product->is_type('variable') ) {
                    $taxonomy = 'pa_color';
                    $colors = explode(',',$product->get_attribute($taxonomy));

                            echo '<div class="colour-swatch">';

                    foreach ($colors as $color) {
                        echo '<div class="swatch '. strtolower(trim($color)) .'">';
                                    echo '<div class="circle">';
                                    echo '<div style="background-color: var(--'. strtolower(trim($color)) .');"></div>';
                                    echo '<a href="' . esc_url( get_permalink( $product_id ) ) . '?attribute_pa_color='. strtolower(trim($color)) .'"></a>';
                                    echo '</div>';
                                    echo '</div>';
                    }

                            echo '</div>';

                }
```

What i need is make it count how many colors it finds inside the loop (so how many times the loop is done). And echo it below.

So if one loop is done, it should (echo "1 color").
If 2 or more colors is found it should echo "x colors" (so include the s on color to make it correct).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// To print the total size of the colors.(the number of times the loop ran)
$sz = sizeof($colors);
echo $sz . (($sz==1) ? " color" : " colors");
```

Comment: Yes this one outputs "1 colors 2 colors" instead of just "2 colors", can u make it so it chooses the highest one?

Comment: What do you need, a total count that you want to echo after the loop finishes?

Comment: Yeah a total count, and if its only one it should say "color" instead of "colors"

Comment: I've updated the solution, give it a try and let me know if it's the same as you want.

Comment: Works like a charm!